# ¿Cómo filtrar un rango de celdas en VBA excel 2013?

Tags: excel, vba

Hola a todos soy nuevo en esto y estoy teniendo problemas en VBA Excel 2013.
Necesito filtrar una base de datos en una hoja, de acuerdo a valores que tengo en otra hoja del mismo libro, estos valores se encuentran en un rango de celdas y están cambiando constantemente, pero el rango de las celdas no.

Primero creí que podia utilizar en el código del filtro donde dice 
AutoFilter field:=1 Criteria:= Sheet1.Range("D4:D10")...etc

Pero no funciona, después intenté hacerlo declarando un array y usando una filtro avanzado, pero no puedo hacerlo funcionar.

Necesito filtrar de esta BD1 que está en la hoja "combustibles".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los valores que aparecen en esta BD2 en la hoja "cálculos"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Refrescando un poco porque ando oxidado en esto de VBA, una forma es convertir tu rango en un array de valores y luego pasarlo a al filtro

partiendo de este set de datos y dejando todo muy clavado (puede dinamizarlo luego)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puede probar algo como lo siguiente:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rango As Range, celda As Range
Dim list() As String, lngCount As Long
Set rango = ActiveSheet.Range("J1:J2")


lngCount = 0
For Each celda In rango
    ReDim Preserve list(lngCount)
    list(lngCount) = celda.Text
    lngCount = lngCount + 1
Next

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=list, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

En mi caso fue probado en Excel 2016 pero entiendo que es igual

Comment: Muchas Gracias Martin!!!! me funciono!!! Solo que me desactivo una macro que tenia asignada a un boton de comando, pero eso ya vere como lo resuelvo, muchas gracias, de todos los codigos que probe solo el tuyo me ha funcionado.

Comment: @albertfernandez: Quizás quieras aceptar la respuesta de Martin. Mäs detalles en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)